# Using NHIbernate and Oracle

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, oracle10g

In a upcoming project I'm going to use NHibernate with Oracle. I have used NHibernate with SQL Server 2005/2008 extensively but have never tried or read much about NHibernate with Oracle.

What are your experiences with Oracle and NHibernate? Are there any major differences from using SQL Server 2005/2008? Any gotch ya's or issues that I should look out for?

The Oracle version is 10g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a recent gig, our group migrated from SQL Server 2005 to Oracle 10g (due to corporate politics...not for any significant technical reasons). Our ORM was NHibernate both on SQL Server and Oracle.

Obviously there were many challenges involved with this migration but very little of them involved NHibernate. NHibernate made this migration much smoother as it abstracted away much database-specific aspects (not all data access was through NHibernate).

We had great success using NHibernate with both platforms. Most of the issues we ran into revolved around Oracle drivers on Windows.

I think you'll find Oracle and NHibernate work well together.

Comment: Unless you want to use CRUD packages... then forget it.

Comment: @Stephanie - Could you go into more detail, maybe give an example?

Comment: @StephaniePage, Are you worried about SqlDialect? This days, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core allows cross platform development using .net core.